# Combining two programs with pipe won't work

Tags: c, cs50

I am supposed to make two programs:

- First program takes a command line argument which is a number, and then it takes more inputs after execution, and if any those equal the command line number you entered, it comes back true, else it comes back false.
- The second program generates a bunch of numbers, and if you want you can give it a seed.

Both of these programs work independently correctly, it stops working when I try to pipeline them (`./generate 1000 50 | ./find 817`).

**Usage:**

```
./find #
```

if number is found: output true, else false

```
./generate [seed]
```

Seeds are generated.

When i try and combine these two commands it doesn't work, I'll see that the generate command generated a number, and wrote `./find` for that number, but it doesn't come out as true.

**Source code for `find.c`**

```
/**
 * Prompts user for as many as MAX values until EOF is reached, 
 * then proceeds to search that "haystack" of values for given needle.
 *
 * Usage: ./find needle
 *
 * where needle is the value to find in a haystack of values
 */

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "helpers.h"

// maximum amount of hay
const int MAX = 65536;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./find needle\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // remember needle
    int needle = atoi(argv[1]);

    // fill haystack
    int size;
    int haystack[MAX];
    for (size = 0; size < MAX; size++)
    {
        // wait for hay until EOF
        printf("\nhaystack[%i] = ", size);
        int straw = get_int();
        if (straw == INT_MAX)
        {
            break;
        }

        // add hay to stack
        haystack[size] = straw;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // sort the haystack
    sort(haystack, size);

    // try to find needle in haystack
    if (search(needle, haystack, size))
    {
        printf("\nFound needle in haystack!\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nDidn't find needle in haystack.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**more `find.c` source code**

```
 /**
 * helpers.c
 *
 * Helper functions for Problem Set 3.
 */

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "helpers.h"

/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    // TODO: implement a searching algorithm
    if(values[4] < 0) {
        return false; 
    }
    if(value < 4) {
        printf("Valid usage: ./search array value\n"); 
        return 52;
    }
    //

    for( long long i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        if (value == values[i])
        {
            return true;
        }

        printf("%i", values[i]);    
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */


void sort(int values[], int n)
{

    int smallest = values[0];
    int smallestSpot = 0;
    for (long long i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {

        for(long long j = i; j < n - i ; j++) //find the smallest int in array
        {

            if(values[j] < smallest)
            {
                smallestSpot = j;
                smallest = values[j];
            }

            values[smallestSpot] = values[i];
            values[i] = smallest;

        }

    }
    return;
}
```

**./generate source code**

```
/**
 * generate.c
 *
 * Generates pseudo random numbers in [0,MAX), one per line.
 *
 * Usage: generate n [s]
 *
 * where n is number of pseudo random numbers to print
 * and s is an optional seed
 */

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// upper limit on range of integers that can be generated
#define LIMIT 65536

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Make sure user gave enough inputs
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./generate n [s]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // convert the string that is inputted to an integer
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    // if user gives a seed, use that seed
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        srand48((long) atoi(argv[2]));
    }
    else 
    {
        srand48((long) time(NULL));
    }

    // create this amount of random inputs
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", (int) (drand48() * LIMIT));
    }

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: to clarify, when I say "use them together" I mean using this command:



./generate 1000 50 | ./find 817

Comment: Can you provide more detail for what you mean by "if I try and combine these two commands"?

Comment: @jeff6times7 I just did, sorry I realize that I forgot to add that.

Comment: The term you're looking for is not "combine" but pipeline.

Comment: @jeff6times7 Alright, thanks. I'm new to C

Comment: Put all details of your question in the question. Don't hide them down in the comments. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I think the logic of `sort` is incorrect.

Comment: @SrulyBrach Actually, pipelining is more of a shell concept that it is a C concept.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The program should be functional without sort working, correct? I didn't implement it in search just yet.

Comment: @jeff6times7 shell meaning command line?

Comment: Also `if(values[4] < 0) { return false; }
    if(value < 4) { printf("Valid usage: ./search array value\n"); return 52; }` What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY make sure they give the command line arguments that they are required

Comment: It is meaningless and harmful for this `search` function.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I guess how I see that it is meaningless, but why is it harmfull?

Comment: 1) Can't target all the elements in the array. 2) `return 52;` This means `true` as a return value.

Comment: I found the root of the problem, not sure what is causing it yet though. For some reason values[0-~100] are being rewritten, if I check for a value later than there it comes out true.

Comment: its sort. Sort being incorrect is what is making the issue

Comment: Aside: I see you use `long long` for indexing arrays. In the 32-bit MSVC I use there will never be enough memory for an index type larger than `int` but if your inplementation does allow more I suggest using `size_t`.

Comment: @WeatherVane What's 32-bit MSVC?

Comment: It is 32-bit compiler producing 32-bit code. I have a 64-bit machine. It is free, and yes, I do know there are better options. But I like my quirky thing, like my friend's quirky Wartburg Knight.

Comment: @WeatherVane you lost me lol, I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: MSVC = Microsoft Visual C. Did you google "MSVC" or even "Wartburg Knight"?

Comment: @WeatherVane no

Comment: this line: `printf("Valid usage: ./search array value\n"); ` does not match this signature: `bool search(int value, int values[], int n)`

Comment: this line: `for (long long i = 0; i < n ; i++)` will generate a `-Wconversion` warning because `n` is declared as `int` and `i` is declared as `long long int`

Comment: the header file 'cs50.h' is non standard, thereby making your code non portable.  Strongly suggest eliminating the user of that header file.  then use the C library functions for input/output

Comment: `EOF` is -1, not int_max

Comment: regarding: `if(values[4] < 0) {
        return false; 
    }`  what is special about the 5 entry in the array `values[]` that you can depend on it being some `>= 0`?

Comment: regarding: `if(value < 4) {
        printf("Valid usage: ./search array value\n"); 
        return 52;
    }` there is nothing in the code that makes ANY difference if the `needle` is < 4.  So why that 'magic' number 4?

Comment: this line: `int smallestSpot = 0;` plus this line: `if(values[j] < smallest)` means that all items in the array `haystack[]` must be less than 0  But, none of the code that generates those values are limiting their output to values that are <0.

Comment: regarding: `if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)`  if argc == 2 then it cannot == 3 so the `&&` (and) will always fail.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Usage: ./generate n [s]\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  2) that message tells the user NOTHING about what the parameters mean.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s numValuesToGenerate [seedValue]\n", argv[0] );

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` ( or better, both ).  variable names like `n` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: I'm not sure, but I do not think that `get_int()` properly consumes the newline sequences.

Comment: to see what is really being passed to the `find` application, you might try using the `tee` shell function, similar to: `./generate | tee find`  as this will echo to stdout the values being passed to `find`,

Comment: the content of the `helpers.h` header file is not listed (and really is not needed at all.)

Comment: the `generate` app is failing to tell the `find` app how many entries will be supplied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search program is too complicated: it is useless to sort the input and it is actually incorrect to try and read all of the input for this purpose:

- reading all lines into an array is a waste of space.
- sorting is a waste of time, comparing each input as it is read is simpler and faster.
- your sorting algorithm is bogus: you do not swap the smallest value into the next index, you just overwrite the value there, the misplaced value is lost.
- you could break out of the loop as soon as the needle is found.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "helpers.h"

// maximum amount of hay
const int MAX = 65536;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./find needle\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // convert needle
    int needle = atoi(argv[1]);
    int found = 0;

    // parse input
    for (int count = 0; count < MAX; count++) {
        // wait for hay until EOF
        int straw = get_int();
        if (straw == INT_MAX) {
            break;
        }
        if (straw == needle) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    // report status
    if (found) {
        printf("\nFound needle in haystack!\n\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("\nDidn't find needle in haystack.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `fount` is typo. 2) `result == 0` --> `found == 1`

Comment: Also It seems useless to continue the loop after the `needle` is found.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: yes, good points. Breaking out of the loop will cause an early termination of the second process, which should not be a problem (same as piping output to the `head` command).

Answer (score 1):

Sort is overwriting the first half or so entries from ./generate.

Comment: Please edit the question, to include this and your above comments. Better: ask a new question which is the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Sorting is unnecessary when doing an exhaustive search with linear search. However, if it is a sorted premise, you can terminate the search halfway. Alternatively, you can use binary search. Since all access is done at the time of reading to the array, it is unaffected by the size of the array if it checks at this point.

Comment: Yeah that was the plan, I just wanted to get half of the thing working first. Thanks